# Resize row contents to fit fixed row height in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview that displays 2 columns of items, which are composed of an ImageView and a TextView below it. This displays fine when the row is using a row height of MATCH_PARENT but I would like to define the row height in a dimensions resource so that I can ensure it's an appropriate height for various devices.

However the problem is that the height I'm trying to set is smaller than the calculated height of the row. I want the contents of the row to be resized so that they fit the row height I've set, but it seems that they're just clipped.

The effect of this is that all I see is the image view, and the text view is hidden because of the smaller row height. I've tried setting the various layout_height settings to various combinations of match_parent / wrap_content, but no luck. Does anyone know how to ensure that the contents of a grid item are resized to fit the item height?

This is the layout of an item in the grid:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/selector_grid_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the grid definition:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

And in the view adapter I'm setting the item view's layout params here:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
    GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.grid_item_height)));
```

Thanks